# Running dotnet publish in Docker container gives "Inconsistency detected by ld.so" error

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I am attempting to upgrade one of my ASP.NET Core projects from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1.  The project uses Docker and one of the Microsoft .NET Core Docker images to build the .NET app, and a Node.JS image to build the JavaScript.  Now that I've switched the build base container from `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2` to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1`, running `dotnet publish` in the container with any arguments returns the following error:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 689: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!

Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

My Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
COPY ./src /app/src

FROM node:8.9.3 AS client-build
# do some npm install / node_modules stuff

FROM build-env as publish
COPY --from=client-build . .
WORKDIR /app/src/
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

Why is `dotnet publish` failing?

Answer (score 0):

There's several things wrong here that contributed to this error.

First, the `WORKDIR` is getting set after the `COPY` operation in the publish step.  Since order is significant, the `COPY` operation winds up copying *everything* in the `node:8.9.3` image (which is Debian 8) into the root of the publish image, which is based on `dotnet/core/sdk:3.1` (Debian 10).  This causes things to be overwritten that should not typically be overwritten when building an application's Dockerfile.

Setting `WORKDIR` *before* doing the `COPY` operation would make the destination of the `COPY` relative to it rather than relative to the image root.  Then, fixing the source path to reference where the outputted JS bundles were located on the `client-build` image cut down significantly on what needed to be copied.  When building a simple application image, it may be clearest to be explicit about the source and destination folders/files to `COPY` with absolute paths, rather than using relative wildcards like `. .`

Separately, the node image used here was significantly out of date (v12.x is LTS as of the time of this writing).  Even though the specified node version was sufficient to run `npm install` and `webpack`, the mistake in the Dockerfile meant that more than just the outputted JS bundles were winding up in the final image, which is a risk.  Updating the node image to either the latest 8.x release, or a more recent LTS release based on Debian 9 or 10 hid the issue, but it's still better to not copy things from one image to another if they're not required.  The reason that "upgrading from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1" appeared to cause this issue is merely the difference from Debian 8 in the old Node image, and the jump from Debian 9 to 10 in the .NET SDK images.

Additional examples related to Docker images for .NET is available here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/README.md